# port.postMessage() in Native messagin does not work as expected in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-native-messaging

I want to create a simple native messaging chrome extension. That is , I need to communicate with the chrome extension through a web and a the web app through the extension.

But when the port message is console.log , no output is given. But the value send by the content script via request.value is displayed. How to fix this problem.

I tried to open vs code here by clicking a button inserted into the web page through the content script and it was successful. Now I want to pass a message from the chrome extension to web page using Native messaging.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Native Messaging Ex",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Native messaging",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["nativeMessaging"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**vs.bat**

```
@echo off
start code
```

**vs.json**

```
{
    "name": "com.vscode",
    "description": "My Application",
    "path": "vs.bat",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://bmnmbagcjohegbabfgkhhmdgph/"
    ]
}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
// runs on the matching webpage

var button = document.createElement('button');
var buttonTextNode = document.createTextNode('Click me to trigger something');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
button.appendChild(buttonTextNode);
body.appendChild(button);

// Event listener
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'info',
    value: 'Hello World from other planet!',
  });
});
```

**background.js**

```
// connect to the native messaging app

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, senders) {
  if (request.type === 'info') {
    var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.vscode');
    console.log(request.value); // Hello World from other planet!

    port.postMessage(request.value); 

    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
      console.log(message); // Nothing here
    });

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in your native app.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you tell me why?

Comment: I can't because I don't see your app's code.